# How disable Backbone.js routing on initial page load

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I know the best practises says "your content must be available on page load" and i did it so.
If user navigates to `/questionnaire/info/id/2`, PHP serves the full html. But problem raises after this point, backbone.js matches the same route and re-requests the same page and loads it with ajax.

How can i disable backbone for current page's first load?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. Just start history with silent: true parameter like this:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, silent: true});
```